# How to verify state change in Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Say in a composable I have two states:

```
var stateA by remember { mutableStateOf(varA) }
var stateB by remember { mutableStateOf(varB) }
```

varA and varB are class variables of type Int and are set elsewhere in the code.

Then somewhere in the composable, in the same scope, I have

```
processA(stateA)
processB(stateB)
```

processA and processB are not composable functions.

So after initial rendering, if neither state changes, then nothing is further processed, that is cool.

Then if say stateB is changed, then both process statements get called.  But I hope only to call processB in the case and not processA.  How can I detect which of the states has changed?

Comment: That's kind of against the point of how the framework works.  It's a Moore style state machine.  You're supposed to be able to draw based solely on the current state, not the path you took to get there.  If you need information that isn't in your state, then your state isn't complete and you need to refactor it so it is.

Answer (score 2):

You should not run heavy processing directly from Composable functions. More information can be found in side effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

In this case, you can use `LaunchedEffect`. Using [`snapshotFlow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#snapshotFlow(kotlin.Function0)), you can create a flow that emits values every time a state changes, so you can process it. You can have a flow for each state, so they will be processed independently.

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    launch {
        snapshotFlow { stateA }
            .collect(::processA)
    }
    launch {
        snapshotFlow { stateB }
            .collect(::processB)
    }
}
```